# Adding elements to a binary Search tree without an order

Tags: sorting, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

I am learning about Binary Search Trees and had a question asking me to add things to a tree and draw what it would look like.

All the ones before this question specified something like "Assume the tree uses Alphabetical ordering to compare words" but this time it doesn't say that.

Is there a default sorting order to sort strings or int's when adding them to a tree?

For context, it asks me to:
    Draw a picture below of the binary search
    tree that would result from inserting the following words into an empty
    binary search tree in the following order: Legolas, Frodo, Sam, Merry,
    Pippin, Aragorn, Gimli, Boromir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question specifically says "Binary search trees", you can compare node using the [Lexicographical order (Alphabetical Order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) while inserting nodes in the tree.

for your example the tree would look like :

```
                                     Legolas


            Frodo                                                 Sam


  Aaragon              Gimili                             Merry


        Boromir                                               Pippin
```

Comment: So if it is unspecified, for strings you add the first item in the list as the OverallRoot, then use lexigraphical (alphabetical) order to arrange the rest of them, based on whether or not the first letter comes before or after the one you just put in. Great, Thanks!  one more question, if it is with integers, I'm assuming you just order them least to greatest unless otherwise specified?

Comment: Yes for integers you have to order by which integer is greater, if the question had said only `"Binary tree"` then you can insert nodes any where in the tree, but for a `"Binary search tree"` it has to have some ordering property in order for it to search an element

Comment: Thank you for you answers! they are very helpful

Comment: No problem, happy to help !